# Find index of symbol in string

Tags: c++, file

I want to find index of '-' in string "book-Buch". What should I do? I mustn't use this function or any others. Any ideas?

```
int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)
```

Comment: Do you want to find the first `-` in a file ... or what does "_I'm working on files_" mean? Please make it a [mcve].

Comment: You are creating an array of `string` and comparing `w[i]` (a string) to `x` (a character). It won't work.

Comment: Unrelated: You may come to regret `int i, j, wc, uw, xx, ii, jj;` If these are loop index variables, define them in the loop that uses them to A) minimize their scope and B) keep the definition with the loop for easier reading. If they aren't loop index variables, they sure look like them and should get more descriptive names to prevent confusion. Also, don't reuse variable names in the same scope, and think twice before reusing variable names even if not in the same scope. You don't want to confuse people. Confused people make bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string word("book-Buch");

  // The easy way
  std::cout << word.find("-", 0) << '\n';

  // The manual way
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < word.length(); ++i) {
    if (word[i] == '-') {
      std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
  }
}
```

If you just want to find the index that a certain character occurs in, you just need to look at each character and check if it's the one you want.

A string can be treated as an array of characters. It's unknown whether you actually want an array of string objects, or are just confused.

Other questions that would need to be answered: do you need to find all occurrences, or just the first? Are you reading the words out of a file? You don't clearly explain how a file comes into play.

Comment: I edited guys. Now it is mire understandable. Waiting for you :)

Comment: My answer doesn't require any changing.